# Should users be allowed to ask people to upvote their post?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973793/gmail-extensions-mail-count-is-not-working) got lots of upvotes recently, probably because [the OP asked people to upvote it in a Chromium bug report (comment #37)](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=379279#c37).

Note that the question, while it was a bug report and not a question, has still been upvoted by at least 10 users. The OP and the "upvoters" don't seem to understand what Stack Overflow is for.

So, my question is, **are people allowed to ask others to upvote a post (question or answer) publicly?**

Comment: I do find it incredible that some people upvoted it when it was still a bug report and hence off-topic for SO... Now, that leaves us with another question: is that question even on-topic?

Comment: "the one who opened this ticket and has now created a ticket on stackoverflow instead" Uh...

Comment: It is really hard to control what users post on other sites. So I wouldn't be to concerned about it. The post can still be handled by the system if actions need to happen.

Comment: How do you intend to stop people from using entirely external media to do this?

Comment: You can't. But, if you notice it, is there something you can do about it? Or is that allowed? I couldn't find any info about that on meta.

Comment: Could you please upvote this comment, please ;-) ......

Comment: There are definitely things you could do about it. For example, if you happen to take the question along with the upvote begging and posted on numerous message boards yourself, it might get downvoted a bunch of times as well to balance it out.

Comment: One thing to remember if you are dealing with a post on a third party site that is asking for upvotes you can't be certain that it was the post's author that is asking for the upvotes or someone who just likes it regardless of them claiming authorship.

Comment: Sure. The terms of service should include language relieving visitors of freedom of speech, press, association elsewhere in society, and any other human rights -- like the right to live --  we find annoying, as well. Wait, that's also us.... :-~

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I find such behavior whorish, but not something worth taking any sort of moderator action on.

Comment: Agreed. I probably thought too much about this...