# Is it OK to leave a comment asking for upvotes?

Tags: support, comments, upvotes, comment-flags, faq-proposed

If lots of other people seem to have the same question, is it OK to ask for those people to upvote my question?

The reason I ask is because I was looking at [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65154810/loading-selenium-user-profile-in-tor-chrome-windows#comment115188121_65154830) (comment now deleted by a moderator, so link is non-functional):

> Many many users seem to be looking for this information..Consider up voting the question. Thanks.

I wasn't sure if this was an appropriate comment, or if I should flag it. I suspect it is a misuse of comments, since the placeholder text in the comment box advises (emphasis added):

> Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. **Avoid comments like “+1”** or “thanks”.

**Is it OK to ask for upvotes in comments? If I see comments like this, should I flag them?**

Comment: ....if you want almost-guaranteed downvotes.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**No**, it is not appropriate to ask for upvotes in comments. No matter how carefully it is done, it inevitably comes across looking like you are begging for votes. Besides, that kind of meta-commentary doesn't belong in comments. As you mention in the question, comments should be reserved for technical questions and suggestions about how to improve a post.

In fact, **it is inappropriate to discuss votes *at all* in the comments, whether upvotes or downvotes**. Voting is anonymous, and should be done solely on the quality of the post, at the voter's discretion. You should not attempt to persuade anyone into voting in any particular way, nor should you praise/criticize people for voting a certain way.

If you see comments on the site that discuss votes, you should flag them as "no longer needed" so that moderators can remove them.

If you see this happening *off-site*, well, I think we can all agree it is [not classy behavior](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258234), but, as Robert Harvey (a former moderator) says, there is not much that we can do about it within the bounds of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes begging for upvotes is obviously bad practice (and could backfire), but the bold statement in this answer is a bit too strong. For example If I saw a comment like *"I don't agree with all the upvotes on this answer, because (list of technical reasons)"*, I wouldn't flag it because it contains useful information. Also it wasn't OP's comment, OP was considering flagging it, so not sure why you are accusing him of vote begging.

Comment: I'm not accusing anyone of anything, @user000001. And yes, you can come up with all sorts of contrived examples. This is why moderators actually *read* the comments when they get flagged. Even in your contrived example, it would be better not to mention votes at all (what if the post score changes in the future?): just list your technical objections.

Comment: @CodyGray What about asking an OP to "Mark as solution"? After a comment of OP thanking you for the solution and saying it works, but they haven't marked as solution after a while, you say "Since this answer works for you, please click the checkmark by the upvote/downvote buttons so that when someone comes to this question in the future, it shows up as 1) having a solution on the preview, and 2) an easy way for a new person to see that this solution works." ?

Comment: I would avoid those, too, @Samathingamajig. They serve little purpose. The Help Center and other in-place tips already tell users how to accept answers, if they want. You want to avoid making it sound like you're trying to pressure someone into accepting your answer. There's never an obligation for anyone to accept any answers.

Comment: @Samathingamajig If I notice an OP has indicated that they're happy with an answer (not necessarily mine), sometimes I comment something like "In case you didn't know: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)" seeing as first-time posters may not yet have read all the help.

Comment: @Andrew - I typically flag those type of comments.  They always seem to be submitted by someone who has submitted the answer never anyone without a skin in the game.

Comment: @SecurityHound I usually check if the OP still seems to be visiting SO so that it won't be a wasted comment. Normally I would leave that comment on an answer that I haven't provided. I even go back and delete it myself if no-one else has flagged it as "no longer needed."

Comment: But when an item gets a downvote and you are pretty sure it's not deserved, but there is no indication by comments or better anwers what's wrong with yours, why houldn't you ask for the reason of the down-vote? After all it opens the possibility that the answer (or question) gets refined and improved

Comment: @Patrick Because nobody will see that comment. Certainly not the actual downvoter, who is long gone. The best you can hope for is someone else who comes by and speculates. But, inevitably, because you mentioned votes, you get into an argument about whether the downvote Is "deserved" (which is a meaningless notion, since downvotes just reflect the voter's opinion), instead of staying focused on the technical aspects and/or routes for improvement. The fact is, anyone who wants to suggest improvements can and will. You don't need to ask first. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393914

Answer (score -1):

Leave a Comment with https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

I do that when someone thanks me in a comment and didn't accept it.

This is a reminder especially for newcomers about how the site works.

It is not begging, but a reminder to do it.

Sadly even long-term members seem to forget, how it works.

Comment: Newcomers are *already* informed by the site about this. Veteran users who choose not to do it are well within their rights to choose not to accept an answer. Leaving "reminders" *is* an attempt to bully them into it, and you should not do it. Even if not bullying, these comments are just noise for all future visitors and serve no productive purpose.

Comment: Assuming that is true, that's even more reason not to leave these kinds of comments.

Comment: @CodyGray newcomers haven't often make the tour, as my answer says when they get the hint, the read the link. You notice, that most make basic errors, so that their questions are often closed. Also you get often the comment for these users to make the tour.

Comment: Leaving that link has it's uses. It explains how it works and is explicit that accepting is voluntary. And it also says to not leave "Thank you"'s in comments. Though I think I've only ever used it on other users posts, where I had no other involvement in the thread.